# How do I get a generic class's method that returns T to return it as Integer when T is integer?

Tags: java, generics

First of all, sorry for asking such a vague question, I did not know how else to put it.

If I have a class Heap:

```
public class Heap<T> {
    private T[] arr;
    private int heapSize;

    public T peek() {
        if (heapSize > 0) {
            return arr[0];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and another method somewhere:

```
double mean(int a, int b) {
    return (a + b)/ 2.0;
}
```

which is called as

```
mean(heapA.peek(), heapB.peek());
```

It throws an error saying `mean(int, int) cannot be applied to (Object, Object)`.

Something like this would have worked for an ArrayList or some other inbuilt structure.

What am I missing here?

Typecasting fixes this but I am just curious as to why this works for say ArrayList but not for my class.

Comment: How did you declare and initialize `heapA` and `heapB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you create ArrayList, you need to create object of Heap.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Did you notice `<Integer>` in the declaration?

```
Heap<Integer> heapA = new Heap<Integer>();
```

Now no need to add casting `mean` method.